# Copy and paste subreport within the main report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that includes a sub report. I need to add a same sub report with minor modification for the report. Is there a way to copy one existing report within the main report, paste it, then go into that new sub report and only have to make the changes required for the slight differences between the sub reports. Please let me know.

Comment: couldn't understand the exact requirement... you want to change the existing subreport or add new sub report?

Comment: I want to add a new sub report that is slightly different from existing sub report. I want to see if there is a way to cut and past existing sub report.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the existing subreport and do a `save subreport as` and save a local copy.
2. now make the necessary changes in that saved copy.
3. Add the changed subreport by using option `insert sub report` and `Existing report.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't see any 'save as' feature when I open existing sub report in my main report. Where is this 'save as'?

Comment: open existing sub report and go to `file-> save as`

Comment: 'Save As' saves the main report. It doesn't save subreport.

Comment: you will see option `Save Subreport as` option when you open subreport and go to file menu. If that option is not presemt then you don't have anyother option rather than again create report fromm scratch

Comment: @codematrix You need to open the subreport in design view, then go to "File" → "Save Subreport As..." (and NOT "Save As" as was original stated; I've corrected this in the answer). You can also try, from within the main report's design view, right-click on the subreport object → "Save Subreport As..."

Comment: Unfortunately, the availability of this feature appears to be based on the version of your Crystal Reports editor.  Using VS 2010 with the Crystal Reports plug in, I do not have this option, but using SAP Crystal Reports 2013, I do.

Comment: I don't have the "save report as" in "File" menu also, but Ryan suggestion works, "right-click on the subreport object" → "Save Subreport As..."

Answer (score 2):

You will need two reports 1) Main Report 2) Subreport

1) Create a new standalone report that will be your Sub report

2) On you Main report, 
   Click Insert Subreport -> Select Choose Existing Report -> Browse to the newly created subreport -> OK.

3) You will have a subreport that want. Now add links between sub report and Main report using Subreport links

4) This way you can add the same report multiple times and then in each subreport, you can do the individual changes you wish to do on each subreport, without having to change the whole report everytime.

Hope it helps.

The slight problem with @Siva answer is if you go into a Subreport and then go File -> Save As, Crystal still prompts to save the Main report which is now incl the Subreport and not the Subreport by itself. Hence in Step 3 Siva's answer the whole Main report would get added, instead of just the subreport.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to do the new subreport all over again. Is there a way to create the subreport based on existing subreport easily.

Comment: Well in that case, if you open your subreport and dont see the Save Subreport option under File menu, then you cannot do that. Creating the subreport again and using it multiple is your best bet

Comment: I opened the subreport in Report Builder, saved it with a different name, then I could add it into Visual Studio 2017 easily. I saved it with the new name in the same subfolder. But all that said Visual Studio seems really buggy, but it did save me recreating the formatting, I just changed one condition in a select statement for the second subreport.