# Copy subreport from one crystal report to another in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a subreport contained inside of a parent report that I would like to be able to re-use it inside of another report.

Some seemingly viable options according to [copy and paste subreport within the main report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22242470/1366033) include:

- Saving as standalone subreport and linking across both parent reports
- Exporting from one file and importing into another
- Copying and pasting

However, none of these operations seem to work from the Visual Studio Crystal Reports Designer

## Here's what I've tried so far...

#### No option to saving as a standalone report ❌

With the subreport selected, here's what I get in the File Menu (there should be an option to "Save *Subreport* As"

[image: No Save Subreport As]
<sup>click images for full res</sup>

#### No option to export from Context Menu or Crystal Report Menu ❌

Here's the Context Menu from right clicking on the sub report

[image: Sub Report Context Menu]

And here's the Crystal Reports Menu

[image: Crystal Reports Menu]

#### No Copy Paste operations when selecting subreport object from main report ❌

[image: No Copy Option]

Here's another thread from Crystal Reports on [How can I copy sub-reports from existing report to another report?](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5217996/how-can-i-copy-sub-reports-from-existing-report-to.html) that seems to suggest the same process.

Maybe this just isn't supported in the Visual Studio Designer?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.11) and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 13.0.24

Comment: I'm starting to suspect, [no, this isn't possible in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23078224/1366033), but workarounds welcome